# NuGet Update Error?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

Using the NuGet package manager dialog at the solution level in the normal course of updating a package reference once the process is complete there is a green tick on the item and the update button disappears.  However, with certain of my packages the update process completes, as far as I can tell successfully, but no green tick and the update button remains. Press it again and the next dialog shows that no projects require an update for that package.

Am I missing something here or is this a bug?

Comment: This is unexpected, I know it happens at the project level when installing solution level packages but I'm not aware of this case.
Do you have a specific example (which packages) ?

Comment: @Alexandre Dion Maybe we are talking about the same thing? I'm not sure what a solution level package is? To my mind all packages references exist at the project level. Using the NuGet Package Manager Dialog is simply an aggregate view/operation?

Comment: If you right-click the solution or go to Tools->Library Package Manager, Nuget Package Manager will open for the solution. If you right-click the project, Nuget Package Manager will open for the project. What you saw could be side effect of a solution-level package that is managed at project level.

Comment: Just to be clear, there's some packages that do not exist at project level, these are packages that do not add any files to a project for example : Nuget.CommandLine, it adds nuget.exe at the solution and is not bound to any project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this can happens when updating [Solution-level packages](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/nuget-faq#What_is_the_difference_between_a_project-level_package_and_a_solution-level_package%3f). For some reason, they are updated side-by-side and the older package version causes the update to always appear as applicable. I filed an issue to clarify this behavior: [#2062](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2062)

Another way that this happens is when packages.config is excluded from the project. The package is updated but the new version is not updated in packages.config. Please, make sure that packages.config is included in the project.